# Can Java ever be based on UTF-8, like 'Go' is?

Tags: java, utf-8

Java is currently UTF-16 natively. I know there are ways to convert to UTF-8.

With Unix already being UTF-8 based (only reference it as Java is mostly run on 'nix), how difficult would it be for Java to get into the UTF-8 arena natively, like the rest of the world is leaning towards, for more efficiency?

Will it involve a total rewrite of the language ?

Comment: Probably you should post this on [Java bug report](http://bugreport.java.com/) and let the guys evaluate it.

Comment: naah, I will just let the trigger happy folks here downvote something they fail to understand.(which goes against my username, i know :) - but you were just joking, weren't you - this isn't really a bug (yet)

Comment: Well, since I can't answer a 'held' question, I found that Java 8 is high-performant ISO 8859-1, which is close to UTF-8, except it comprises of the first 256 Unicode which is what is important anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with UTF-8 is that you cannot implement `charAt` method with O(1) performance. There are many code in the world which rely on this. Something like:

```
for(int i=0; i<string.length(); i++) {
    char c = string.charAt(i);
    ...
}
```

If you switch to UTF-8, looking for i-th character will be O(n), thus such code will become O(n^2) which can become performance disaster.

As for efficiency there's a proposal to revive [compressed strings](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8054307) in Java: strings consisting solely of ASCII-7 characters can be stored in `byte[]` array. As far as I know, this feature is being actively developed and the are *chances* that it will be included in JDK9.

Comment: The problem you mention, would that apply to ASCII characters too ?

Comment: Nope. There will be two string representations: 1 byte per each symbol (if all the symbols are Latin-1) and 2 bytes per each symbol (for all other cases). In both representations you can quickly get an i-th symbol. In UTF-8 you have mix of 1-2-3-etc. bytes per symbol in the same string, thus you will actually need to check all the previous symbols.

Comment: How does Go overcome this

Comment: I'm not a Go expert, but seems that they don't have methods for random access by position. Only sequential iteration is possible. After all they don't have tons of legacy code like Java has.

Comment: So can I take i that your answer is Java will never switch to UTF-8 because of this (or for any other reason) ?

Comment: I'm not a fortune teller. I'm even not a Java developer. It's unlikely, that's all I can say. For more information read the comments in the linked bugreport.

Comment: Such `charAt()` loops do not usually handle Unicode codepoints outside the BMP, which require UTF-16 surrogates (two `char`s acting together). `charAt()` does not decode surrogates, it returns the surrogates as-is. But `codePointAt()` does decode surrogates.

Comment: @Tagir - in UTF-8, for the ASCII symbols, wouldn't it still be just one byte ?